# JSP Java Script validation not working

Tags: javascript, jsp

I wrote a java script code in a  JSP  page,But when i try to submit the Page, my javascript validation code is not getting fired,Could any one help me what went wrong?

Here My Code:

```
<html>
<center><h3>Employee Absent Report</h3></center>

<head>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function onFormSubmit(){
    var countErrors = 0;

    var strDt=document.getElementById("startdate").value;

    var endDt=document.getElementById("todate").value;
    var flag=false;
    var eFlag = false;

    if (IsEmpty(strDt)==false && IsEmpty(endDt)==true ) {       
        document.getElementById("divExpiryDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Expiry Date";
    return false;

    }

    if (IsEmpty(strDt)==true && IsEmpty(endDt)==false ) {       
        document.getElementById("divStartDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Start Date";
        return false;


    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="FormServlet" method="get" onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(); ">
<center>
<div id="formErrors" class="error"></div>       
FromDate:
<input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate"/>
 <div id="divStartDate"></div>
<br>
ToDate:
<input type="text" name="todate" id="todate"/>
 <div id="divExpiryDate"> </div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</center>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: look for errors in console. I suggest you to use chrome, it has great developer console.

Comment: Open you IE Dev toolbar and check for the error it gives. I think the issue is with `IsEmpty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a logical error to me. Try replacing this:

```
if (IsEmpty(strDt)==false && IsEmpty(endDt)==true ) {       
    document.getElementById("divExpiryDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Expiry Date";
return false;

}

if (IsEmpty(strDt)==true && IsEmpty(endDt)==false ) {       
    document.getElementById("divStartDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Start Date";
    return false;


}
```

with:

```
if (endDt.length==0) {       
    document.getElementById("divExpiryDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Expiry Date";
return false;
}

if (strDt.length==0) {       
    document.getElementById("divStartDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Start Date";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is there a method "IsEmpty" in javascript? I think that's the problem. If you have that defined in some other place, try running your code in Firefox and watch Error Console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Do the validation this way

```
if (endDt === "") {       
    document.getElementById("divExpiryDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Expiry Date";
    return false;
}

if (strDt === "" ) {       
   document.getElementById("divStartDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Start Date";
   return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

this is the working modified code

```
  <script>
    function onFormSubmit(event){
        var countErrors = 0;
        event.preventDefault();
        var strDt=document.getElementById("startdate").value;
        var endDt=document.getElementById("todate").value;
        var flag=false;
        var eFlag = false;
        if ( IsEmpty(endDt)==true ) {    
            document.getElementById("divExpiryDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Expiry Date";
        eFlag = true ;
        }

        if (IsEmpty(strDt)==true  ) {    
            document.getElementById("divStartDate").innerHTML = "* Please Enter Start Date";
            eFlag = true;
        }
        if(eFlag)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function IsEmpty(input)
    {
       if(input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")    === "") {
           return true;
       }
      return false;
    }
```